# Missing Work Place Switcher

Tags: workspaces

I have no icon for the Work Place Switcher in Ubuntu 14.04

I have used the "switcher" many Linux distributions ago.  I'm also migrating from Windows and would like to have different desktops for different applicational use.  Nice to see Windows 10 see such a function useful.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable workspace switching in Ubuntu 14.04LTS, by default, Workspace switching is off.

Settings > Appearance > Behaviour > Enable Workspaces.

That's all. ctrl+alt+arrow_keys will let you go through workspaces.